# how to set unique entry in glocery crud with respect to another field

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to add city in a table by using glocery crud library in codeigniter. 
So i use a function

```
$crud->unique_fields('state');
```

which is working fine . But how to handle if same state_name exist in different countrystate.
My database table is like this

```
`id` `country_id`  `state`   `status`
 1     1             abc         0
 2     2             abc         0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create composite unique key for that.

```
$crud->unique_fields('country_id', 'state');
```

Comment: It is not working as i want because making both unique country_id and state respectively .. but if i have same state name in multiple country ( assume the case)